# Manjaro Linux desktop file stored in ~/Desktop is not working

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, .desktop

I've stored a chromium desktop file in ~/Desktop and added some `actions` .Although I can see the icon and on clicking the default `Exec` gets executed but I don't see any options on right clicking the icon. But when I added the same file in `~/.local/share/appliactions` and ran `update-desktop`, I can see the options in start menu but not in the desktop.I'm using Manjaro.